# How to convert Multiple row values to one row with comma-separated value different ID in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I am trying to return data in comma separated values with below query.

```sql
select u.employeeid,
       ( select name
         from   roles r
         where  r.id = ur.role_id
       ) userrole
from   users u,
       user_role ur
where  u.id in (select DISTINCT ur.user_id
                from user_role ur)
order by u.employeeid asc;
```

Current Output:

```
EMPLOYEEID USERRROLE
---------------------
1000    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
1000    ONBOARDING_CHECKER
1000    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
1000    ROLE_APPROVER
1000    ROLE_ONBORDING
```

Now when I execute the query, I want table to be like:

```
EMPLOYEEID USERRROLE
--------------------
1000       ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN,ONBOARDING_CHECKER,ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN,ROLE_APPROVER,ROLE_ONBORDING
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LISTAGG` (and ANSI joins rather than legacy comma joins and confusing sub-queries). What you probably want is:

```sql
SELECT u.employeeid,
       LISTAGG( r.name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY r.name ) AS userrole
FROM   users u
       INNER JOIN user_role ur
       ON ( u.id = ur.user_id )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN roles r
       ON ( r.id = ur.role_id )
GROUP BY u.employeeid
ORDER BY u.employeeid asc;
```

Although I think what you have actually written would be:

```sql
SELECT u.employeeid,
       LISTAGG( r.name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY r.name ) AS userrole
FROM   users u
       CROSS JOIN user_role ur
       LEFT OUTER JOIN roles r
       ON ( r.id = ur.role_id )
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM   user_roles x
                WHERE  u.id = x.user_id )
GROUP BY u.employeeid
ORDER BY u.employeeid asc;
```

Comment: getting `01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"` error

Comment: and also i want to get few more columns from `users u` table

Comment: @Durga A `VARCHAR2` data type (which is what `LISTAGG` returns) can store up to 4000 characters. If your concatenated string is longer than that then you will get that error and your options are: (1) truncate the string to 4000 characters; (2) find a custom aggregation function that concatenates strings to a CLOB; (3) use XML to concatenate the value (but you won't have a comma separated string, you'll have XML); or (4) use the `CAST` and `COLLECT` functions to return a collection (array) of strings rather than a delimited string. There are solutions for all of those options on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Durga "i want to get few more columns from `users u` table" .... [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58231437/edit) your question with a [MRE] that includes: DDL statements for your table structures; DML statements for some example data in those tables that demonstrates the issue; and your expected output for that input. Just saying "i want more" is not constructive as we can't determine what "more" you want.

Comment: @Durga . . . Don't edit this question.  MT0 has answered the question that you asked.  If you have a *new* question, ask it as a new question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd agree with you if the "more" is new features that are tangential to the existing question then it should be a new question; however, if the "more" is the answer generally right but isn't quite doing what I want (as maybe the `INNER JOIN` needs to be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) and it isn't clear from the existing data then editing the question to clarify the exact requirements is the way to go.

Comment: I would answer the question differently, rather than aggregating by all the desired columns the OP wants.  The solutions would look different.  Plus, I think you have a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

this will do:

```
SELECT LISTAGG("USERRROLE", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "USERRROLE")
FROM Table1 group by "EMPLOYEEID";
```

check fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d11c6/4

Thanks!!!!!!!